# Whether range of matrix $A^TA$ is the same as that of $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I cannot ensure whether column space of $A^TA$ is the same as $A^T$, if it is, how to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key observation is that $N (B)=N (B^TB) $. Then  $$R (A^T)=N (A)^\perp=N (A^TA)^\perp=R(A^TA). $$

Comment: but why is $N(B) = N(BB^T)$?

Comment: It's a typo. It should have been $N (B)=N (B^TB) $, which is just $$0=Bx \iff 0=(Bx)^TBx.$$